# Efficient debugging approach for Postman

Tags: php, codeigniter, postman

I have been using Postman to develop APIs in php for my product using CodeIgniter framework.

To debug my code, I have to track controllers and models using `echo` and `print_r()` to identify the actual error as it does not provide error message.

> **While using CodeIgniter:** When some error exists in model, Is there any way to identify error from controller when using Postman?

Please help if you are aware of better debugging methods in Postman.

Answer (score 0):

If it's something wrong with your PHP code, it's better off to look at the log messages to determine what the errors are rather than looking at Postman.

Another great tool to use for debugging is [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/)

Comment: You mean log messages generated by `error_reporting();`. I have tried it but it fails to show me the errors in my model. Thanks for XDebug, seems pretty useful.